# How does one reduce the animation delay time with animate.css?

Tags: css, css-animations, animate.css

I recently became aware of the "flip" transition offered by animate.css. My website is heavily UI oriented, so I wanted to add some life to button clicks by adding the "flip" transition. It's great, except that there is a ~1 second delay after the button click before the flip occurs.

I scanned the css file on GitHub, and the only time-related code I saw was:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.0s;
    animation-duration:1.0s;
}
```

I shortened these to 0.5s each but this only made the flip occur more rapidly once the animation occurred.

I tried adding the following delay-related css to .animated.flip buttons

```
.animated.flip {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

but still no change.

I also added the same css rules to button.animated.flip, but again no effect.

How do you reduce the animation delay time when using animate.css?

Comment: Please provide a snippet, or atleast a link.

Comment: What browser are you testing on?  I ask because it looks like the list of possible vendor prefixes supplied in animate's CSS file might not be complete.  MDN's page, for example, seems to indicate that -moz- is needed as a prefix for animation duration: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: @Jeff Mahoney, I tested on FF/Chrome/IE/Opera all latest versions

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm ... well, I downloaded animate.css and jquery, and did not experience any click-button delays with the flip transition when I used it.

I called it like this from the sample page I whipped up:

```
<body>
  <button id="mybutton" onclick="flipit()">Flip It</button>
</body>
<script>
  function flipit(){
    $('#mybutton').addClass('animated flip');
  }
</script>
```

In fact, I wasn't able to see any delay until I **put** one in the animate.css file, like this (at around line 1653 in the animate.css file):

```
.animated.flip {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;  /* <-- my added delay */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
          backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: flip;
          animation-name: flip;
}
```

I ran this on Chrome and Safari on a MacBook Pro.  I only included the -webkit-prefaced version of the delay to keep the sample short, but it worked with -moz and -o too (and also disappeared too when I stripped it back out of the animate.css file).

Hopefully this sheds some light!